# How do I show $ H_n (\mathbb{D}^2 , \mathbb{D}^2 - 0 ) \cong H_n ( \mathbb{D}^2 , \partial \mathbb{D}^2 )$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I am kind of lacking of intuition for questions like that. I see that a chain in $\mathbb{D}^2 - 0$ can be continuously transformed into a chain in $\partial \mathbb{D}^2$, but with the relative homology, I have problems to understand.

Comment: Observe that $\mathbb{D}^2-0$ is homotopy equivalent to the boundary of disk.

Comment: I saw that, but the relative homology is defined as the Homology of $S_n ( \mathbb{D}^2 / S_n ( \mathbb{D}^2 - 0 )$ and so I cannot apply directly homotopy invariance.

Comment: What tools do you have available? Could you use long exact sequences, homotopy invariance, or the 5 lemma?

Comment: All of the things you mentioned, i guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We know that $D^n-0$ is homotopic to $\partial D^n$, but you're right, this doesn't follow immediately from excision.

Take the long exact sequences for the pairs $(D^n, \partial D^n)$ and $(D^n, D^n-0)$. Since we have an inclusion $\partial D^n\hookrightarrow D^n-0$ which is a restriction of the identity on $D^n$, then we have a map from our $(D^n, \partial D^n)$ long exact sequence of homology groups to our $(D^n, D^n-0)$ sequence of homology groups.

$$\begin{array}
A H_k(D^n) & \stackrel{}{\longrightarrow} & H_k(\partial D^n) & \stackrel{}{\longrightarrow} & H_k(D^n,\partial D^n) & \stackrel{}{\longrightarrow} & H_{k-1}(D^n) & \stackrel{}{\longrightarrow} & H_{k-1}(\partial D^n)\\
\downarrow{id_\ast} & & \downarrow{i_\ast} && \downarrow{f} & & \downarrow{id_\ast} & & \downarrow{i_\ast}  \\
H_k(D^n) & \stackrel{}{\longrightarrow} & H_k(D^n-0) & \stackrel{}{\longrightarrow} & H_k(D^n,D^n-0) & \stackrel{}{\longrightarrow} & H_{k-1}(D^n) & \stackrel{}{\longrightarrow} & H_{k-1}(D^n-0)\\
\end{array}$$

The reason we have this map between exact sequences is purely formal, but we need to use the fact that our inclusion is a restriction of the identity to make sure all our little squares commute. Notice we obtain an induced map $f:H_k(D^n, \partial D^n)\rightarrow H_k(D^n, D^n-0)$ for all $k$. The two maps to the left and the right of $f$ are isomorphisms on homology, because the identity induces an isomorphism (obviously), and the inclusion $i:\partial D^n\hookrightarrow D^n-0$ is a homotopy equivalence. We then use the five-lemma to conclude that $f$ is an isomorphism.

Let $n=2$ and we're done. Notice that this argument only needed $D^n-0$ to deformation retract onto $\partial D^n$, so there is an obvious generalisation there.